# What will happen if I append the element that is already removed from DOM, into a documentFragment? does the element get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found this pice of code in Angularjs's source code.

[https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L2014)

```
/**
 * This is a special jqLite.replaceWith, which can replace items which
 * have no parents, provided that the containing jqLite collection is provided.
 *[...]
 */
function replaceWith($rootElement, elementsToRemove, newNode) {
  var firstElementToRemove = elementsToRemove[0],
      removeCount = elementsToRemove.length,
      parent = firstElementToRemove.parentNode,
      i, ii;

  if ($rootElement) {
      ...
  }

  if (parent) {
      ...
  }
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  fragment.appendChild(firstElementToRemove);
  newNode[jqLite.expando] = firstElementToRemove[jqLite.expando];
  for (var k = 1, kk = elementsToRemove.length; k < kk; k++) {
    var element = elementsToRemove[k];
    jqLite(element).remove(); //<----- IF THIS NODE IS REMOVED FROM DOM
    fragment.appendChild(element); //<----- WHAT DOES THIS DO?
    delete elementsToRemove[k];
  }

  elementsToRemove[0] = newNode;
  elementsToRemove.length = 1;
}
```

I'm puzzled by the last part of the code. The documentFragment is not append or referenced. so what is the point of removing the element from the DOM and then appending it to the document fragment?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Maybe the code did something after the loop which someone deleted without looking at the rest of the code.